# Incorrectly displayed plot band icon in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I am trying to create a graph with plot bands in Highcharts, where I want to insert an icon into the plot band.

It all works well except that I cannot get the icon to show below the actual series line. I set the zIndex of the icon to 1 and series to 2, but it seems to not do anything.

I looked at the documentation here:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands.zIndex

But it should work based on that, but it does not, it works when I use text for the label, but not an image and the object has no specific class or ID so that I could target it with jquery and set the css manually.

To illustrate my point I made a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qwfj4x3j/

I used for example

```
 {
    color: null,
    zIndex: -1,
    from: 3.5,
    to: 4.5,
    label: {
        text: "<img src='http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/rain.png' style='width:100px;z-index:-1'>",
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    useHTML: true,
    y: 25
    }
```

},

As you can see, I set the zIndex of both the plot band and the actual image, and a higher zIndex for the series, but it does not work.

Comment: Does not look too good. This is what I found. http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/image-in-plotband-instead-of-label-t14907/ - What I see is that the `span` object is created outside the Highcharts `svg` object, and I see no real way to make that work the way you wanted. So, does it have to be an image within the plotband, or could it also be a positioned background image for the svg object?

Answer (score 0):

If you render an image in that way HTML `<img>` will be rendered at the top of the svg - this is why the image covers svg elements.
Instead, you can use chart.renderer.image() method combined with axis.toPixels() methods to get x, y attributes in pixels.

```
var img;

function renderImage() {
    var chart = this;
    img = chart.renderer.image(
              'http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/rain.png', 
               chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(0), 
               chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(10), 
               150, 
               150
          )
          .add();
}

function redrawImage() {
    img.attr({
      x: this.xAxis[0].toPixels(0),
      y: this.yAxis[0].toPixels(10)
    });
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qwfj4x3j/2/

To have the image responsive like plot lines you need to adjust x, y attributes on redraw event.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so in the end I found a very elegant solution :)
I gave all the images a class and then after the graph is rendered, I call jquery command that targets all parent elements of this class, the span I originally needed to target, but could not because it had no class or id. Now I can call all these as parents of my image with particular class, asign them z-index of -1 and it works :)